# VS2019 - ViewBag does't exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019, viewbag

I have installed VS 2019 for Mac and started building an application. In my view, I get the following errors:
The name ViewBag does not exist in the current context.
The name Layout does not exist in the current context.

What could be the cause for the issue and How could we resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `../Views/Web.config` file, because you created the project from an empty ASP.NET application instead of using an ASP.NET MVC template. Or You need to add MVC-specific Razor configuration to your web.config.

In your web.config file you should add the following lines:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <!-- Your namespace here -->
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: It will happen because of many reasons. Does `_ViewStart.cshtml` contain `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` or `Layout = "_Layout";`? Did you tried it on different .NET versions? Did you installed some extensions on your Visual Studio, If so, you should repair the VS installation? It's possible that your VS installation is not the latest version and is just a pre-release version of it, in this case you can fix the problem with installing a stable version.