# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac: "The name layout does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a ASP.NET MVC application in VS19 for Mac. However, before I add anything myself to the framework, I get the error "The name 'Layout' does not exist in the current context" in the _ViewStart.cshtml file.

I have looked at similar questions on this topic and haven't managed to solve it. My Views\Web.config file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="Vidly" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I looked at this similar question: [VS2019 - ViewBag does't exist in current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151473/vs2019-viewbag-doest-exist-in-current-context) which gave some code to add into the web.config file, but it was the same as what I already had in mine (aside from some of the versions which I have more recent ones).

Answer (score 0):

in _ViewStart.cshtml make sure you have this,

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and in /Views/Shared make sure you have this file _Layout.cshtml

under References check to make sure you have System.Web.WebPages.

Comment: Thanks - I made sure I had those three things configured, but still getting the same problem.